# My phone is making weird music when I am not touching it

Tags: rooting, motorola-moto-g, music, antivirus

My Moto G play just stared to do weird stuff, it started to play a really creepy music that I didn't even have on my phone. Google play music an Spotify (which are the two apps that I use for music) are not open. I never download a hacked app and my phone have not been rooted And I never been on suspicious websites. Can I solve the problem without reseting all the phone?

Answer (score 0):

Put your phone in [Safe Mode](https://motorola-global-en-uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/105621/p/30%2C6720%2C9390) and see if you are still hearing that music. If it stops, that means a user installed app is running in background. Now, depending on the Android version you are running, you can check for running apps in Settings> apps> Developer Settings> Running Apps and try to stop all the apps from running and see which one was playing the music.

(If you don't see developer settings goto Settings> About and tap 7 times on the build number)